# Crawl a music website to get it lyrics

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-crawler

I want to crawl a lyrics website: http://mp3.zing.vn/bai-hat/Vi-Anh-La-Soai-Ca-Dam-Vinh-Hung/ZW78EUE8.html to get the song's name, artist, genre and lyrics.
Then I write the following code and save it as mp3_spider.py

```
import scrapy

class MP3Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "mp3"
    start_urls = ['http://mp3.zing.vn/bai-hat/Vi-Anh-La-Soai-Ca-Dam-Vinh-Hung/ZW78EUE8.html']

def parse(self, response):
    yield
    {
        'song': response.css('.txt-primary h1::text').extract()[0],
        'artist': response.css('.artist-track-log a::text').extract()[0],
        'genre': response.css('.genre-track-log::text').extract()[0],
        'lyrics': response.css('.fn-content::text').extract()[0]
    }
```

I ran it in command line:

```
scrapy runspider mp3_spider.py -o mp3.json
```

but it returns nothing.
Can anyone show me how to make it works? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I suspect that the `parse` method should be defined inside the class.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Your class, `MP3Spider`, doesn't actually do anything because `parse` is a standalone function there. If you indent `parse` to match the indent like this, it'll at least run.

```
class MP3Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "mp3"
    start_urls = ['http://mp3.zing.vn/bai-hat/Vi-Anh-La-Soai-Ca-Dam-Vinh-Hung/ZW78EUE8.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        yield
        {
            'song': response.css('.txt-primary h1::text').extract()[0],
            'artist': response.css('.artist-track-log a::text').extract()[0],
            'genre': response.css('.genre-track-log::text').extract()[0],
            'lyrics': response.css('.fn-content::text').extract()[0]
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty of recreating the scenario and aside from the previous poster answer.... Indentation levels are extremely important on how Python interprets your code: what to do, not to do next or before. In addition:

```
 def parse(self, response):
        yield
        {
            'song': response.css('.txt-primary h1::text').extract()[0],#here
            'artist': response.css('.artist-track-log a::text').extract()[0]#here,
            'genre': response.css('.genre-track-log::text').extract()[0],#here
            'lyrics': response.css('.fn-content::text').extract()[0]#here
        }
```

May I ask how do you come up with you extract values?  I assume you might not use "scrappy shell 'your.com... I assume because by inserting what you had it would tell you that the ranges.. = [0] .... does not exist, at least for the path selected.

I took the liberty in fixing you code up.. But since I don't know Vietnamese
, you might have to mess around with some of the regex.

Tips:

1. Though not necessarily important, when you are scraping content that has paragraphs, its best to go with using itemized selections, tend to make the grouping of large bodies of text easier and less regex needed in my experience.
2. Get used to using Scrapy shell function and do all your path selections in there. This will sqave you much time if you use it AND make a habit of very first thing type view(response). Dynamically loaded pages or web pages that block Scrapy's default agent header just won't be easy as just a regular page (still pretty easy, there are always ways around that).

```
_author_ = 'Tô Vạn Hưng'
__credits__ = 'scriptso' #just helping a brother from the far east
import scrapy

class MP3Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "mp3"
    start_urls = ['http://mp3.zing.vn/bai-hat/Vi-Anh-La-Soai-Ca-Dam-Vinh-Hung/ZW78EUE8.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        yield
        {
            'song': response.css('s.fn-name::text').extract(),
            'artist': response.css('.inline h2::text').extract_first(),
            'genre': response.xpath("//div[@class='inline']/h2/a[contains(font.font,'')]//text()").re('[^\n].*\w')[2:],
            'lyrics': response.css('.fn-wlyrics.fn-content::text').re('[^\n].*\w+'),
        }
```

Comment: Hi there, I appreciate very much your effort Inn correcting  my butchered post, believe it or not there was once upon a time that sentence formation and proper idea structure was actually my forte... Fast forward 6 years of nothing but bastardize,social media ,  colloquial use of any written form to convey myself has been the only form of  I Express on to others. Programming  has now become my true form of expression at the cost of sounding illiterate...  English grammar Refresher courses in order.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I try to run your code but it seem doesn't work. I don't know what I've missed. By the way, can you show me how to get xpath and css? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hey there!  hmmm... 1. What version of python are you runin this project under ass? 2.  Please, when your code execution is not working, please provide the trace back or error log output... a complete detailed response is vital to troubleshooting and you would do good to just get used to doing so as much as possible!!  soo... what error are you getting?

Comment: @TôVạnHưng have you give up on this scrapy project or are you still having issue running it? Please remember to upgrade you scrapy.... I totally missed your question on how to obtain xpath .. If you still wish me to give you my pointers, create a question and mention me in it or/and link it here, already have it all written just worried of getting flagged for answering a question inside a question on here.